# Issue with python cvxpy when trying to get the number of positive variables

Tags: python, cvxpy

I have a python dataframe with one column called "STOCK", another column called "WEIGHT", another column called "EXPECTED_RETURN", and another column called "SOURCE".
The dataframe has both the portfolio and a buy universe.

```
# generate random data for the portfolio dataframe
portfolio_data = {
    'STOCK': ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'FB'],
    'EXPECTED_RETURN': np.random.uniform(low=0.01, high=0.05, size=5),
    'WEIGHT': [0.2,0.1,0.3,0.15,0.22],
    'SOURCE': ['PORT'] * 5
}
portfolio = pd.DataFrame(portfolio_data)

# generate random data for the buy universe dataframe
buy_universe_data = {
    'STOCK': ['stock{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 101)],
    'EXPECTED_RETURN': np.random.uniform(low=0.01, high=0.05, size=100),
    'WEIGHT': [0.0]*100,
    'SOURCE': ['BU'] * 100
}
buy_universe = pd.DataFrame(buy_universe_data)

# concatenate the two dataframes
df = pd.concat([portfolio, buy_universe], ignore_index=True)
```

My goal is to optimize the portfolio by maximizing the portfolio EER.
However, I also have a soft constraint. I need to make sure the final number of securities is close to 30.
I'm trying to achieve this without using a vector of boolean variables, but just the vector with all the weights:

```
n = df.shape[0]
wgts = cp.Variable(n * 2, nonneg=True) # first n = sales, second n = buys
diag_matrix_neg = np.eye(n) * -1.0
diag_matrix_pos = np.eye(n) * 1.0
matr = np.hstack((diag_matrix_neg, diag_matrix_pos))
net_wgts = matr @ wgts
final_wgts = net_wgts + df['WEIGHT'].values
port_er = cp.sum(cp.multiply(final_wgts, df['EXPECTED_RETURN'].values))
num_final_securities = n - cp.sum(final_wgts <=0)
obj_func = cvx.Maximize(port_er)
```

The codee breaks where I try "cp.sum(final_wgts <=0)". Why?

Comment: You cannot use constructs which mix cvxpy with arbitrary python function. You have to adhere to certain rules. And there is no easy "trick" to avoid boolean variables and a proper mixed-integer model.